# Add Records button is missing in Data Extension - Records Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

[image]

The Add Records button is missing in Data Extension - Records Page. As per screenshot, there is only Import, Export and Clear Data button.

Answer (score 1):

Because Email Studio does not provide this option. Only in Contact Builder, you can manually [add](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_add_records.htm&type=0)/[edit](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_edit_records.htm&type=0)/[clear](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_remove_record.htm&type=0) records.
[image]

Important note for consideration to be able to find and then selectively edit or clear some records from Data Extension in Contact Builder, this Data Extension should have a Primary key.